# Activity has leaked window that was originally added (problem in superclass show())

Tags: java, android

I have some dialog popups in app. If I kill app while dialog popup is raised I am getting below crash error.

```
2020-11-26 10:09:25.275 15274-15274/? E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.myproject.v1.HomeActivity has leaked window DecorView@d75132a[] that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:418)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
    at com.helper.DialogHelper.show(DialogHelper.java:71)
    at com.myproject.v1.HomeActivity.pointDialog(HomeActivity.java:1592)
    at com.myproject.v1.HomeActivity.onClick_LevelInfo(HomeActivity.java:1604)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4720)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I have seen many similar problems in stack but they are not same to my problem bcs my problem is not in dialoghelper class it is in superclass show(). I have tried to solve in dialoghelper dismiss while activity destroying but didn't fix bcs showing problem is in dialoghelper but it is beforedialog helper.

Answer (score 0):

The view is trying to show a Dialog after it has exited the Activity.
Make sure you close the dialog before leaving the activity.
Call `dismiss()` on the Dialog instance you created before exiting your Activity, e.g. in `onPause()` or `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`
Like

```
@Override public void onStop() { if (dialog != null) { dialog.dismiss(); }}`.
```

Also make sure you do a `null` check for the dialog before displaying it.
 
Like
`if (dialog != null) { dialog.show(); }`